# Can I set multiple TXT record on my DNS? (in order to proove the ownership of a domain to 2 mailboxes system)

Tags: domain-name-system, outlook, microsoft-office-365, txt-record, dns-record

I am not a system\network engineer (I am a software developer) so this is not my cup of tea.

I have the following problem: I am configuring some Office 365 mailboxes for a client (that at the moment is using another old mail service).

Following this official documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-with-domains/create-dns-records-at-any-dns-hosting-provider?view=o365-worldwide

I have to add the **TXT** record (provided into the Office 365 control panel) in order to proove that I have the ownership of the specified domain.

So this is not my territory and I have the following doubt: at the moment they are using another e-mail system (that will be replaced but that must still work for some days, I can't stop it now).

So set this **TXT** record means to **add a new TXT record** (in order to prove thath I own this domain). In this case I will have 2 **TXT** record (one for Office 365 and the other one for the old memail system and both should works fine) or it means that I have to replace the old TXT record? (in this case I suppose that the old e-mail system will not recognize my domain anymore and it could be a problem).

So my doubt is: in a domain can I have more that a single TXT record? This can have some impact on the old e-mail system that must still work for some days?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> Can I set multiple TXT records on my DNS?

Yes, any name on the DNS can have multiple `TXT` records attached to it. There is no real practical limit.

Also, `TXT` records to prove ownership are typically short term: once ownership is proved you can most of the time remove them without problems. But double check with the entity requesting the presence of those `TXT` records.

Answer (score 2):

> in a domain can I have more that a single TXT record?

Yes. It's not uncommon to find DNS zones with multiple TXT records for validation of a variety of services, such as Microsoft 365, Google Workspace, etc., etc.

The TXT record has no relation to your email.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could configure multiple txt records on your DNS, Since a domain supports multiple TXT records.

Here are some similar threads for your reference: [Multiple TXT fields for same subdomain](https://serverfault.com/questions/815841/multiple-txt-fields-for-same-subdomain) and [Can I add two TXT records in DNS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60665380/can-i-add-two-txt-records-in-dns)